# mysql:select and insert from same table

Tags: mysql, select, sql-insert

Need suggestion.
And, I've 2 tables like **master and slave**.

`master` contains 3 columns following as:

```
searchTerm    | group   |campaign
------------------------------
apple macbook |  null   |null
apple ipad    | null    |null
```

And `slave` contains 2 columns and multiple entries following as:

```
group | campaign
----------------
apple | Laptops
```

***Note: if apple is found in `serachterm` of master table and then `group and campaign` should be inserted in the `master table` and run in joins for all `slave tables` entry***

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you produce any query? What output are you expecting?

Comment: hey you wants to display the table like, `m.searchterm|m.group|m.campaign|s.group|s.campagin`

Comment: not sure if it is possible with sql query..i am expecting if group matched from slave table in to searchterm of master table then group and campaign should be inserted..

Comment: no jmail,it will be like m.searchterm,s.group,s.campaign if match found

Comment: thanks @jmail but i am trying to search s.GROP value in each row of m.STERM,if found will insert in to m.GROP and m.CAMPIGN.Hope you understand..

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
 insert into slave (group,campaign) select group campaingn from maseter 
 seachterm=your search term
```

Answer (score 0):

*her this one will be going to solve you problem*

```
select * from master;
select * from salve;

SELECT m.id,m.sterm,s.grop,s.camp
FROM master m
INNER JOIN salve s
ON m.id=s.id;
```

*you should refer this [**link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77193/1)*

Answer (score 0):

in mysql

```
update master m
inner join slave s
on m.searchterm like concat('%',s.group,'%')
set m.group = s.group,
m.campaign = s.campaign;
```